# Access specific fields in firestore security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to write some security rules for my firebase database in firestore. I have a database with some recipes in it and each recipe has one field called userId which is the user id of the user who created said recipe. What I want to do is write security rules that only allows the user with the matching uid update the recipe. Something like:

```
match /Recipes/{document=**} {
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
  allow update: if request.resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
}
```

The part I am wondering about is how do I access the userId from the field in the recipe? I've tried `request.resource.data.userId` as above but that doesn't work.

Comment: request.resource.data.userid should be correct. Can you share you client side code?

Comment: Also, you should probably ensure that the userid is properly populated on create

Comment: It works now, I was just not testing it correctly. Thanks for the help! :)